# Conditional shift in pandas to create new columns

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset/datafame looks like this:

[image]

I want to add six more columns week-1, week-2, week-3, sales-1, sales-2, sales-3 in the dataframe. Week-1 is the current week minus 2, week-2 is the previous week and week-3 is next week. Similarly, sales-1 is the sale of the week before previous week, sales-2 is the sale of the previous week and sales-3 is the sale of the next week.
In the case of fiscal week 202201 the previous week and the one before the previous week is absent, hence the 3 weeks after 202201 become week-1, week-2, and week-3. For 202202 the week before the previous week is absent so 202201, 202203, and 202204 become week-1, week-2, and week-3. For fiscal week 202205, next week is absent, hence 202202,202203,202204 are the three candidates. Similarly, the values for sales-1, sales-2, and sales-3 are chosen.
**In short select 4 rows including the current row where the first 2 rows are the two above the current row, and the last row is the one after the current rows. If the current row is positioned in such a way that any of these positional rows are absent then this window is shifted downward/upward to get a 4-row window including the current one.**

This is what the final dataframe should look like:

[image]

Currently I am implementing it using 2 for loops:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
for item in df['ItemNo'].unique() :
    df_temp = df[df.ItemNo==item].sort_values(by=['Fiscal_Week'])    
    sale_wk_minus2 = []
    sale_wk_minus1 = []
    sale_wk_plus1 = []
    wk_minus2 = []
    wk_minus1 = []
    wk_plus1 = []
    
    for i in range(len(df_temp)):
        if(i==0):
            wk_m2 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i+1]
            wk_m1 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i+2]
            wk_p1 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i+3]
            sale_m2 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i+1]
            sale_m1 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i+2]
            sale_plus2 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i+3]

        if(i==1):
            wk_m2 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i-1]
            wk_m1 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i+1]
            wk_p1 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i+2]
            sale_m2 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i-1]
            sale_m1 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i+1]
            sale_plus2 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i+2]
            
        if(i==( len(df_temp)-1)):
            wk_m2 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i-3]
            wk_m1 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i-2]
            wk_p1 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i-1]
            sale_m2 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i-3]
            sale_m1 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i-2]
            sale_plus2 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i-1]
            
        if((i>1) and (i<len(df_temp)-1)):
            wk_m2 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i-2]
            wk_m1 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i-1]
            wk_p1 = df_temp. Fiscal_Week.iloc[i+1]
            sale_m2 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i-2]
            sale_m1 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i-1]
            sale_plus2 = df_temp.Sales.iloc[i+1]
            
    df_temp['week_minus_2'] = wk_minus2
    df_temp['week_minus_1'] = wk_minus1
    df_temp['week_plus_1'] = wk_plus1
    
    df_temp['sales_minus_2'] = sale_wk_minus2
    df_temp['sales_minus_1'] = sale_wk_minus1
    df_temp['sales_plus_1'] = sale_wk_plus1

    df_final = pd.concat( [df_final, df_temp])
```

Can we implement it more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

This would roughly be my approach. You can add in the missing sales data
by re-indexing the DataFrame so you can look up sales using a combination of week and ItemNo directly.

Also I haven't taken care of the final/highest week yet.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ItemNo": [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29],
    "Fiscal_Week": ["202201", "202202", "202203", "202204", "202205"] * 2,
    "Sales": [45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62],
})
```

```py
df["Week"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Fiscal_Week"], format="%Y%m").dt.to_period('M')
df["Week-1"] = df["Week"] - 2
df["Week-2"] = df["Week"] - 1
df["Week-3"] = df["Week"] + 1

# Overwrite first week entries
week0idx = df[["Week-1"]].idxmin()
week0 = df.loc[week0idx,"Week"].iloc[0]
week0idxs = df["Week"][df["Week"] == week0].index
df.loc[week0idxs,["Week-1","Week-2","Week-3"]] = [week0 + 1, week0 + 2, week0 + 3]

# Overwrite second week entries
week1idx = df[["Week-1"]].idxmin()
week1 = df.loc[week1idx,"Week"].iloc[0]
week1idxs = df["Week"][df["Week"] == week1].index
df.loc[week1idx,["Week-1","Week-2","Week-3"]] = [week1 - 1, week1 + 1, week1 + 2]
```

The task is somewhat weird, it would make more sense to me to have "week minus 3", "minus 2", "minus 1", and "plus 1", and leave the unknown ones empty...